# Can a Muggle-Repelling Charm Be Broken?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, magical-theory

Hermione is notorious for quoting *Hogwarts, a History* regarding protective enchantments, magic that makes Hogwarts Unplottable, and Muggle-repelling charms that hide Hogwarts from Muggle eyes and make the castle and grounds appear as an ancient ruin with "Danger" signs.

**Are there circumstances under which a Muggle-repelling charm can be *broken*, such as with a charm or spell, Dark Magic, or a potion? What about a specific number of Muggles, Aurors, or beasts bearing down on the protected area?**

**ETA:** I should have made triple sure to stress when asking my question that I'm talking about Muggle-repelling charms being ***broken***, not lifted at will to allow the parents of Muggleborns to help their children shop for books at Flourish and Blotts, to see them off on the Hogwarts Express, or to visit their child at a time of need (or just if they want to visit their child in general at Hogwarts and make arrangements to do so). So I've emphasized **"*broken*"** in my question -- **is there anything that can *break* a Muggle-repelling charm?**

Here are some questions and answers that already deal with Muggles in the Wizarding world and/or Muggle-repelling charms and the issue of the families of Muggleborns having access to the Wizarding world:

[**Do Muggle parents visit their Muggleborn children at Hogwarts?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18383/do-muggle-parents-visit-their-muggleborn-children-at-hogwarts-are-they-totally)
[**Who gets Muggleborn children onto Platform 9<sup>3/4</sup>?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/who-gets-muggle-born-students-onto-platform-9-3-4)
[**Why are some Muggles allowed to know about the Magical world?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/why-are-some-muggles-allowed-to-know-of-the-magical-world)
[**Does the Invisibility Cloak work on Muggles?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12322/does-the-invisibility-cloak-work-on-muggles)
[**Is a Squib a Muggle?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-a-squib-a-muggle)
[**Can a Muggle become a potions-maker?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/can-a-muggle-become-a-potions-maker)
[**Are Muggleborn wizards automatically subject to Wizarding law?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22050/are-muggle-born-wizards-automatically-subject-to-wizarding-laws)

I'm not interested in these above cases of the charm being **lifted**, but broken.

<sub>I'm looking for an answer based in canon -- the *Harry Potter* novels and the supplemental books, JKR interviews, or Pottermore information. I do not prefer an answer from the HP Wikia or the Wikipedia.</sub>

Comment: Wasn't the one for the _Goblet of Fire_ Quidditch match temporary?

Comment: @Izkata -- I don't know, to be honest. I don't recall that, but if you check it out and find that that's so, then please do leave an answer :)

Comment: Re: your update: as I stated in my answer, in Potterverse, there doesn't seem to be a functional difference between "breaking" and "lifting" a charm - merely the intent, unless the charm is somehow uniquely complicated and not known to "breaker", like Voldemort's Horcurx protextions. But Muggle Repellant doesn't count into that as it's well known. You're welcome to disagree of course :)

Comment: I'm interested in intent, or the lack of intent, or whatever might be strong enough to break the charm whether intentionally or unintentionally. It seems, though, that the intentional breaking of a Muggle-repelling charm has been pretty thoroughly examined in other questions, so that's why "break" and "lift" have a different feel to me. :)

Comment: Does Muggle Repellent contain DDT? Will Muggle repellent cause thin eggshells in the various bird species native to Great Britain? Should it be regulated, and perhaps kept from small children and/or pregnant women? Is it humane to use muggle repellent, could they perhaps use some sort of live trap or pheromone lures, or even cultivate plants whose odor causes muggles to stay away?

Comment: Would it have to be broken by a Muggle?

Comment: I'm not sure you have enough related questions here :p Very thorough as usual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Dragons** have such magical powers that they can sometimes cancel out Muggle-Repelling Charms:

> Some of these safe areas must be kept under constant wizarding supervision; for example, dragon reservations. While unicorns and merpeople are only too happy to stay within the territories designated for their use, dragons will seek any opportunity to set forth in search of prey beyond the reservation borders. **In some cases Muggle-Repelling Charms will not work, as the beast’s own powers will cancel them.**
>   <sub>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* - page xix - Scholastic - *Magical Beasts in Hiding*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can be temporarily lifted.

One example was Muggle parents arriving at Hogwarts. For example, Moaning Myrtle's parents came to pick up her body (it's mentioned in the diary's memory of Tom Riddle talking to Hagrid). Myrtle was a Muggleborn.

I'm not aware of canon example where they were broken by a hostile force, but for "stock" Muggle-Repelling Charm this is not relevant. Why?

- Unlike some other magical universes, magic in Harry Potter is "impersonal" and doesn't have weird quirks like "only a caster can affect the spell the cast afterwards", assuming it is a standard well known charm.
- In other words, if Dumbledore or a prior headmaster could lift the "stock" Muggle-repelling charm on Hogwarts, so could Voldemort or any other wizard of equal power and knowledge.
- Please note that this only applies to charms themselves, NOT their effects. E.g. a muggle-repelling charm can be lifted, BUT the results of obviate done by Lockhart on himself can not be.

Comment: Regarding your second point, that doesn't hold. Dippet was Headmaster of Hogwarts at the time the Muggle repelling charm would've been lifted. Headmasters have power over the protective spells on Hogwarts simply by virtue of being Headmaster (recall McGonagall's control of Hogwarts defenses during the final battle after Snape left the post). Voldemort would have to become Headmaster, and have Hogwarts recognize his Headmastery (we see with Dolores Umbridge that isn't a given), in order to lift the Muggle repelling charm.

Comment: @GabeWillard - sorry, unless you have canon proof otherwise, I strongly disagree. You don't have a special "Headmaster version of Muggle repellent spell". He may have had to lift OTHER defenses that were not easily done by outsiders. But this Q was specifically about a very stock very well known no-special-configurations spell

Comment: Do you have a "Headmaster version of a anti-Apparition charm"? Because we are explicitly told that only the Headmaster can lift that protection during the Apparition classes in Year Six. You're leaping to a conclusion unsupported in canon, at best, since there are clearly Headmaster specific restrictions to spells that we don't fully understand.

Comment: @GabeWillard - Are you sure that only Headmaster is **able** to lift the Anti-Apparation charm (as opposed to **allowed**)? I don't have the quote on me

Comment: The quote says, "‘As you may know, it is usually impossible to Apparate or Disapparate within Hogwarts. *The Headmaster has lifted this enchantment,* purely within the Great Hall, for one hour, so as to enable you to practise. May I emphasise that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try." It does not say if anyone else can or not. However, would Voldemort not lift the charm **if it were within his power to do so?** I think that itself is compelling evidence it may be impossible.

Comment: After all, breaking a charm sounds like an easier plan than having a student fix a pair of Vanishing Cabinets up.

Comment: @GabeWillard - Not canon, but I am sure Voldemort would be prevented from lifting Anti-Apparition charm by **not being able to apparate or otherwise enter Hogwarts** :)  And Drako wasn't exactly on the level of being able to do so - it's not exactly a Year 1 level charm, i would guess

Comment: @GabeWillard I think it could be that breaking the charm takes longer than lifting it, and thus affect the element of surprise.
It may also be that Hogwarts, as a magical place, is ruled by similar rules to wandlore and the school chooses the headmaster, and as Dumbledore was alive when Umbridge took over, the allegiance of the school did not change.

Comment: "Unlike some other magical universes, magic in Harry Potter is "impersonal" and doesn't have weird quirks like "only a caster can affect the spell the cast afterwards", assuming it is a standard well known charm. " - I think what @GabeWillard was trying to get at is, Dolores Umbridge wasn't able to enter the Headmaster's office even though she officially held the position, so it _seems_ like there's something special going on there

Comment: @Izkata - it could simply be some spell she didn't know or wasn't powerful enough to cast OR lift.